# Как написать под текстом текст в файле?

Tags: java, файлы

Как записать под определенным текстом текст в файле?Например:название файла file.txt
Текст:

> Hello
>
> Hi
>
> Hey

Например как записать текст под текстом "Hi"?

P.s.Некотрые напишут про `split();` но я не знаю как это сделать правильней.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если учесть, что файл может быть очень больших размеров, у меня получилось такое решение:

```
Path input = Paths.get(fileName);
Path output = Files.createTempFile(input.getFileName().toString(), "$1");
try (BufferedWriter br = Files.newBufferedWriter(output)) {
    Files
            .lines(input)
            .map(str -> {
                if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
                    return str + System.lineSeparator() + text;
                else
                    return str;
            })
            .forEach(str -> {
                try {
                    br.write(str);
                    br.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}

Files.move(output, input, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```